# Why recast a pandas groupby object as a dataframe to write to excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

If I read a csv file into a pandas dataframe, followed by using a groupby (pd.groupby([column1,...])), why is that I cannot call a to_excel attribute on the new grouped object.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("some file.csv")
data2 = data.groupby(['column1', 'column2'])
data2.to_excel("some file.xlsx") #spits out an error about series lacking the attribute 'to_excel'
data3 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
data3.to_excel("some file.xlsx") #works just perfectly!
```

Can someone explain why pandas needs to go through the whole process of converting from a dataframe to a series to group the rows?

---

I believe I was unclear in my question.
Re-framed question: Why does pandas convert the dataframe into a different kind of object (groupby object) when you use pd.groupby()? Clearly, you can cast this object as a dataframe, where the grouped columns become the (multi-level) indices. 
Why not do this by default (without the user having to manually cast it as a dataframe)?

Comment: Please show the output from `data.head()`.

Comment: Because all you have is a `groupby` object with no aggregations performed, the error shows that `Series` objects have no `to_excel` method this is expected operation, it looks like you want to set the index to those columns and then export to excel

Comment: Also note that in general, doing `pd.DataFrame(groupby_object)` will raise an error! That is not meant to work, and it actually suprises me (can you give some example data for which this works?)

Comment: Further, if you want to set certain column as the multi-level indices, you don't need groupby at all, but just a `data.set.index(['column1', 'column2'])` call!

Comment: I think there might be something incorrect about the line data3=pd.DataFrame(data=data2). I think it might be interacting with the previous definition of data. The reason I say this is that my groupby objects can't be converted with a call to the DataFrame constructor with data= pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your reframed question about why `groupby` gives you a groupby object and not a DataFrame: it does this for efficiency.  The groupby object doesn't duplicate all the info about the original data; it essentially stores indices into the original DataFrame, indicating which group each row is in.  This allows you to use a single groupby object for multiple aggregating group operations, each of which may use different columns, (e.g., you can do `g = df.groupby('Blah')` and then separately do `g.SomeColumn.sum()` and `g.OtherColumn.mean()`).

In short, the main point of groupby is to let you do *aggregating computations* on the groups.  Simply pivoting the values of a single column out to an index level isn't what most people do with `groupby`.  If you want to do that, you have to do it yourself.